# Remove style from dropdown check list

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, checkbox

I am using [this](http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html) drop-down checklist for one of my applications. This works well for me, but my problem is, its Look(jquery UI) doesn't match with my application UI. Is there any way to change the style of the above. I prefer to remove the stye and look like normal drop down list. I had also gone through [this](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/). But it has the same problem. Is there any drop-down checklist that look likes normal dropdown, and has this functionality?

My code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#s1").dropdownchecklist(); 
        });
    </script>

            <select id="s1" multiple="multiple" tabindex='8'>
                <option>Low</option>
                <option>Medium</option>
                <option>High</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try removing already assigned class and style or what ever works, after removing these attributes add new class to dropdown

```
$('#dropdownid').removeClass();       
$('#dropdownid').removeAttr('class');
$('#dropdownid').removeAttr('style');    
$('#dropdownid').attr('class', 'newclass');
```

Try to change in the css of this drop down provided in ui.dropdownchecklist.standalone, ui.dropdownchecklist.themeroller

Comment: Did you try to change in the css of this drop down provided in ui.dropdownchecklist.standalone, ui.dropdownchecklist.themeroller?